# How to run service in loop in android even when app is closed

Tags: android

I have created a service that sends StringRequest to a server and gets response. Now i want this service to keep on sending and getting response even when my app is closed. but i can only get it done once. Please anyone guide my how to keep looping in a service?
Here is the code i want the service to repeat

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String URL = "Some URL";
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        RequestQueue myQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest myRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("My Log", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("My Log", error.toString());
                    }
                });
        myQueue.add(myRequest);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to run a service forever even if when the app is not running, you should probably use [foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). another way to achieve this is [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your service is probably still alive after execution of `StringRequest`. your problem is that this happens once, at start. create inside `onCreate` some `new Handler` instance and use `postDelayed` for interval requesting (reset `Handler` and start again in `onResponse` and `onErrorResponse`

but above will be working as long as your app is on foreground (`Activity` visible). on newer system versions (9+, most on market currently) you have to use [`ForegroundService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) with sticky `Notification` informing that something happens in the background in context of your app

Comment: I want to simulate what whatsApp does. You are connected to internet but even when the app is closed you get notification that a message has arrived. I think whatsapp does this in background service.

Comment: there are plenty of methods for doing that, e.g. you may set up `AlarmManager` and interval short requesting for status in short-living one-shot `Service`, but most of apps are using some push messaging services, like [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: Thank you for info. I will search into that